# Converting Avro to ORC in Java?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, orc

I'm looking to create a bunch of ORC files from Avro messages consumed from Kafka.

I saw some sample code using Spark below. I am just running this in a standalone process and wondering what sorts of options I should look into. I want to pump these files into a cloud storage like S3 for example. Is there a recommended way of doing this?

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Converter Service")
    .setMaster("local[*]");

SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

// read input data
Dataset<Row> events = sparkSession.read()
    .format("json")
    .schema(inputConfig.getSchema()) // StructType describing input schema
    .load(inputFile.getPath());

// write data out
DataFrameWriter<Row> frameWriter = events
    .selectExpr(
        // useful if you want to change the schema before writing it to ORC, e.g. ["`col1` as `FirstName`", "`col2` as `LastName`"]
        JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(outputSchema.getColumns()))
    .write()
    .options(ImmutableMap.of("compression", "zlib"))
    .format("orc")
    .save(outputUri.getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Databricks avro reader](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-avro.html) for Spark to create dataframes. Spark natively supports ORC, so the file creation is a cinch.

You'll find the Avro library [in Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.6).

In Scala, it would loook something like this:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.format("avro").load("/tmp/episodes.avro")
// From string: val df = spark.read.avro(Seq(avroString).toDS)

df.write.orc("name.orc") // You can write to S3 here
```

Comment: Do I need spark context and all that running for this to work?

Comment: Yes. I added the details for a spark session in my answer above.

Comment: Databricks has an avro reader. That should greatly simplify your work and make the addition of a Spark dependency worth your while. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Lars. So can the Spark dependency exist in the same container as the code that does the conversion? I want everything to packaged as a single thing, but not too familiar with Spark

Comment: Yes. Once you have included Spark in your container, adding the dependency is simple.

Comment: You'll probably want to run this through spark-submit. You can find an intro on how that works with a fat jar here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-build-single-executable-jar-file-assembly/